# Bootstrap Switch doesn't switch

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying a very simple straight forward integration of Bootstrap Switch (http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/), however for some reason, the switch won't toggle. No errors are given by the system, it just doesn't change status when I click it (tried on Windows 8 - Chrome).

My code for testing is following (I'm using the JS and CSS directly from their site to prevent any errors from that):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Some title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/vendor/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/build/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">


    <div class="has-switch switch-animate switch-on" tabindex="0"><div><span class="switch-left">ON</span><label for="switch-change">&nbsp;</label><span class="switch-right">OFF</span><input type="checkbox" id="switch-change" checked=""></div></div>

 </div> <!-- /container -->

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/docs/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/build/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I also had to include the index.js that they are using. After that everything worked.